# Что будет быстрее? Сохранять и фильтровать или фильтровать и сохранять?

Tags: php, https, ssl

Есть необходимость собирать информацию с https страниц. Использую PHP

```
<?php
$url = 'https://www.google.com';
function getSslPage($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}
getSslPage('https://www.google.com');
echo getSslPage($url);
$file = 'c:\file.txt';
file_put_contents($file, getSslPage($url));
?>
```

Вместо гугла использую другие сайты. Все хорошо, но сохраненный код составляет 15-30 тысяч строк, а сам текстовый файл весит свыше 1мб. Весь процесс на моем не мощном (мягко сказано) ПК занимает порядка 3 секунд. С этого файла мне нужно не более 10-20 строк. Что было бы быстрее:

1. Получать код в переменную без сохранения в файл, искать нужную
   информацию и сохранять эти 10-20 строк в файл?
2. Или же в любом случае сохранять код и только потом искать нужные мне
   строки?

Answer (score 0):

Любые операции с жестким диском намного медленнее чем с оперативой и процессором. Сам недавно столкнулся с проблемой ресурсов - все дело в том что когда оперативная память переполняется - идет запись на жесткий диск и вот тут начинаются жесткие тормоза. Обычно собирают информацию при помощи парсеров с использованием библиотек например php DOM аналог jqwery или регулярным выражением. Если есть возможность хранить информацию в базе данных - то будет намного лучше. Почему? Дело в том что хранения в базах данных и извлечение отлично оптимизированы.